# Trying to obtain Run As value for SQL Server Job steps

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to obtain the Run As value for each of the job steps within each SQL Agent job on SQL Server 2012.

This is manifestly not the login value (`sysjobsteps.database_user_name`) as it does not correspond to Run As value selected.

Example: Job MP Backup has one step `Subplan_1` which was generated by saving a Maintenance Plan to perform database backups.

(side note: using MPs for backups is a different conversation...)

Opening the Job Step Properties in SSMS for this step shows SQL Server Agent Service Account in the Run as dropdown.

This is the value I seek, but has proven elusive to locate.

Joining sysjobsteps to sysproxies results in NULLs for sysproxies.name, which is not surprising as proxies have not been employed for the steps in any jobs.

I suspect I'm simply overlooking something, but don't know where else to look.

Answer (score 1):

For SSIS job steps it's the `ProxyID` column.  This is probably NULL for you right now because "SQL Server Agent Service Account" is the default.

Comment: I'm trying to understand how this works; are you suggesting the value of NULL automatically translates to SQL Server Agent Service Account? NULL is also appearing for other Step Types, e.g. Transact-SQL (T-SQL) and Operating System (CmdExec), to name two.

Comment: Yes, for SSIS step-types, ProxyID=NULL means the step is Run As the SQL Server Agent Service Account.  I am not sure about the other step types, T-SQL steps default to the Job's owner, I believe.